# Is it possible to change the instance name for MPRIS/DBUS?

Tags: electron, chromium, electron-builder

I'm still an Electron novice, so pardon me if this is a stupid question. But I'm working on a Linux project that's connected to a media player created with Electron and electron-builder. We'd need to target this player by it's MPRIS or DBUS name. So when the player is on and we run e.g. `playerctl --list-all`, the player has a generic name like "chromium.instance145392".

Now the question is, can this name be changed to something custom, like "thebestplayerever.instanceXXXX" instead, so that we could find it? Or is this out of scope for Electron, something that is done on Chromium's side?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @NotSimon, nope, unfortunately I didn't find any way to get it working. Don't know if things have changed since and there are new possibilities though...